# insert a blank page in between pages of a web-based report using chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have these html/css code that inserts a blank page between pages 2 & 4 in IE11. How can I tweak this to behave the same way in Chrome? Thanks.

```html
<htmL>
 <head></head>
<body>
 <div><span>hello 1</span></div>
 <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
 <div><span>hello 2</span></span>
 <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
 <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
 <div><span>hello 3</span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `style="page-break-after:always; page-break-inside:avoid"`?

Comment: No it doesn't work.